# How to assign multiple echo outputs to a variable and store it a text file

Tags: bash, echo

I am trying to read multiple echo outputs and assign it to a variable and store it a text file one by one.

```
echo docker-virtual.artifactory.com/dotnetcore:latest
echo docker-virtual.artifactory.com/images:latest
echo docker-virtual.artifactory.com/nginx:latest

var="$(echo "docker-virtual.artifactory.com/dotnetcore:latest")"
echo $var > docker.txt
```

But here how to read multiple `echo` outputs and assign it to a variable and store in a text file one by one like all outputs. When I tried everytime it re-writes and store only one value, so how to achieve this.

Comment: Do you need any variables? You can wrap the three `echo` statements into a single command group and redirect the output of the group to `docker.txt`. `{ echo ...; echo ...; echo ...; } > docker.txt`

Comment: @chepner Yes I want to wrap the three `echo` statements into a single command group but  is it possible to use a separate line for echo statement one below the other and redirect the output to a `docker.txt` ?

Comment: No, because the output isn't saved anywhere (except in whatever file is being used for standard output. What exactly are you doing (or trying to do) that the command group is not sufficient?

Comment: Your question may be too simplified to convey what you actually need or want.

Comment: @chepner I have tried using `echo` in a single command group but I am not getting output as expected.   `{ echo docker-virtual.artifactory.com/dotnetcore:latest;echo docker-virtual.artifactory.com/images:latest;echo docker-virtual.artifactory.com/nginx:latest } > docker.txt`  .  **output**: `$ echo $docker.txt
.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it simpler to assign values directly?
like this

```
var_dotnet="docker-virtual.artifactory.com/dotnetcore:latest"
var_images="docker-virtual.artifactory.com/images:latest"
var_docker="docker-virtual.artifactory.com/nginx:latest"
```

If you insist on echoing, do the following:

```
var_dotnet=$(echo docker-virtual.artifactory.com/dotnetcore:latest)
var_images=$(echo docker-virtual.artifactory.com/images:latest)
var_docker=$(echo docker-virtual.artifactory.com/nginx:latest)
```

now, you can write this variables to the file:

```
echo "$var_dotnet" > docker.txt
echo "$var_images" >> docker.txt
echo "$var_docker" >> docker.txt
```

Please note ">>" - it appends to the text file, while ">" rewrites it.